# Flutter permissions handler doesn't allow to run lines below

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a request of a permission for camera, but Permission.camera.request() doesn't return result and it doesn't allow to run the below lines on Android.

Flutter version v1.12.13+hotfix.5

```
Future<bool> _requestPermission() async {

if(resultReq==null)
resultReq = await Permission.camera.request();

print("it works!");

if (resultReq.isGranted) {
  return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because isGranted is not a getter function instead if you use

> resultReq == PermissionStatus.granted

it will work smoothly, the complete modified code of your function :

```
Future<bool> _requestPermission() async {
    var resultReq;

    if(resultReq==null)
      resultReq = await Permission.camera.request();

    print("it works!");

    if (resultReq == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      print('accepted');
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```